# Can differently grouped ICollectionViews still be synchronized between controls?

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose I have an in-memory collection of sports players including the college they attended, position they play, and current team, bound to 3 different controls (ListBoxes) in order to browse different players by those 3 different groupings

Is it possible to synchronize the 3 controls with different ICollectionViews so that a selection in one is synchronized with the others? Or is this only possible if they are all bound to the same ICollectionView instance? I have the 3 ListBoxes already set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" but I suspect this only works if they're using the same ICollectionView?

This is what I'm doing in my code:

```
        ICollectionView collegeView = new ListCollectionView(playerDatabase);
        collegeView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("CollegeName"));
        collegeView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("CollegeName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        collegeView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("FirstName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        lstCollege.ItemsSource = collegeView;

        ICollectionView positionView = new ListCollectionView(playerDatabase);
        positionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("PositionCode", new NFLPositionGrouper()));
        positionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("PositionName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        positionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("FirstName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

The playerDatabase variable is coming from a LINQ to Entity query projecting an anonymous type.

BTW there are approximately 2000 rows in the original database - it seems like the initial interface takes a noticeable 1 second to draw itself initially is there any other way I can do this more efficiently? As long as I don't replace the ControlTemplate and thus remove the VirtualizingStackPanel (I do however have DataTemplates for the ItemTemplate and HeaderTemplate) I won't unintentionally disable item virtualization will I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CollectionView` acts much like a View in a database in that it is kind of like a live snapshot of the actual data which you can group, sort, filter, etc.  If you are using 3 separate CollectionViews, I don't believe `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` will work in this case because I believe that may depend on a single, `ICollectionView`.

However there is no reason you couldn't create a property in your ViewModel (are you using MVVM? If not, I'd highly recommend it) which represents the CurrentPlayer and bind the `SelectedItem` property of all the ListBoxes to this property (make sure the property raises the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event).

Comment: I'm not using a VM for this example - I was just trying to solve this in a vaccum, but that is a very good suggestion however - I like it! I was just wondering if I was using the View objects incorrectly